# Get remaining days and append to select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

and thank you in advance. I'm far from a sql developer but have some experience and i feel as though this should be fairly straightforward.

I found the query below that returns the remaining days in the month. It works like a charm. But when i try  to append it to a simple select statement fetching data from a table i can not append it as a column. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Declare @DaysLeft as INT

;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 as 'CurrentDay'
    FROM   master..spt_values
    WHERE  type='p'
    AND    number < datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
           DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),
                                     number) ) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

Select @DaysLeft = (Select COUNT(*) As MyTotal from MyCTE
WHERE CurrentDay >= DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()))

Select @DaysLeft as 'Remaining'
```

What i am attempting:

```
 Select column 1, column 2 , Remaining (code from above) from TableName
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but try replacing the last line with `Select column 1, column 2 , @DaysLeft as 'Remaining' from TableName`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simpler way to get the remaining days in the month:

```
with remainingDays as (
      select dateadd(day, 1, currdate) as dte
      from (select cast(getdate() as date) currdate) x
      where month(dateadd(day, 1, currdate)) = month(getdate())
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte) as dte
      from remainingDays
      where month(dateadd(day, 1, dte)) = month(getdate())
     )
select *
from remainingDays;
```

It uses a recursive CTE, but there should not be that much overhead for this type of operation.

[Here](http://rextester.com/RVAB11950) it is in Rex Tester.

Comment: How can you switch that out with my answer below? I could not get it to run

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that worked. Much appreciated. Here is my final query:

```
Declare @DaysLeft as INT
;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 as 'CurrentDay'
FROM   master..spt_values
WHERE  type='p'
AND    number < datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
                                      DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),
                                     number) ) not in     ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

Select @DaysLeft = (Select COUNT(*) As MyTotal from MyCTE
WHERE CurrentDay >= DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()))


SELECT column 1, column 2, @daysLeft 'remaining'
FROM    TableName
```